# Why in one thread works but not in another one?

Tags: javascript

Why the thread works in `document.write` but not with innerHTML? When using innerHTML I get just 'Z'.

```
<body>
    <p id="datt">Recount of Alphabet</p>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>    
        function tet() {
            // var Mi_num = 0;
            // var Resul = 130;
            var alph = new Array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","K","L","M","N","O","P","S","Q","R","T","Z");
            for (var i = 0; i < alph.length; i++) {
                 document.write(alph[i] + "<br>");  
                 // document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = alph[i] + "<br>"; 
                 // with this method I get just the letter 'Z'
            }   
        }
        window.addEventListener("load",tet,false);
    </script>
</body>
```

Is the innerHTML level different than `document.write`?

Comment: You're setting `.innerHTML= ...` a new value on every round of the loop overriding the previous value. Create a variable for the text, _add_ values to that variable in the loop , and set `innerHTML` only once after the loop. And __don't use [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)__.